# Most elegant solution for internationalization with JPA / Hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, internationalization

Dear Stackflow Community,

I wish to store internationalized strings in my entities, and I am struggling with how to approach this. I will describe here the two solutions which I can think of, and would appreciate to receive your feedback.

## Solution 1: Externalized from entities

In this solution I have the following table in my database:

```
LabelId         Language    VALUE   Entity              Id

WELCOME_TEXT    EN          "..."       Questionnaire   1
WELCOME_TEXT    DE          "..."       Questionnaire   1
GOODBYE_TEXT    EN          "..."       Questionnaire   1
GOODBYE_TEXT    DE          "..."       Questionnaire   1

QUESTION_TITLE  EN          "..."       Question        12
QUESTION_TITLE  DE          "..."       Question        12

OPTION_NAME     EN          "..."       Option          23
OPTION_NAME     DE          "..."       Option          23

FACTOR_NAME     EN          "..."       Factor          11
FACTOR_NAME     DE          "..."       Factor          11
```

I would access this collection always with the following methods:

```
void setLabels(Entity entity, LabelId labelId, Map<String, String langValues)
Map<String, String> getLabels(Entity entity, LabelId labelId)
```

## Solution 2: With collection of elements

In this solution, all entities have Map stored in the same table:

```
LabelId         Language    VALUE   questionnaire_id    factor_id   question_id option_id

WELCOME_TEXT    EN          "..."       1
WELCOME_TEXT    DE          "..."       1
GOODBYE_TEXT    EN          "..."       1
GOODBYE_TEXT    DE          "..."       1

QUESTION_TITLE  EN          "..."                                   12
QUESTION_TITLE  DE          "..."                                   12

OPTION_NAME     EN          "..."                                               23
OPTION_NAME     DE          "..."                                               23

FACTOR_NAME     EN          "..."                       11
FACTOR_NAME     DE          "..."                       11
```

Then, I would map all the fields in my entities in the following format:

i18n.java:

```
@Entity 
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"label", "language", "questionnaire_id", "question_id", ... })})
public class i18n extends PersistentObject { // where it gets ID from
    Label label; // enum

    Language language; // enum

    String value; // the actual text

    // bi-directional links to the linked entities
    @ManyToOne Questionnaire questionnaire;
    @ManyToOne Question question;
    ...
}
```

Questionnaire.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "questionnaire")
List<i18n> labels;
```

Question.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
List<i18n> labels;
```

## Solution 3: The non-solution

Another simple way to do this would be to simply store a map like this for every property:

```
@ElementCollection
Map<String, String> welcomeText;

@ElementCollection
Map<String, String> goodbyeText;

...
```

This solution creates A TON of tables in my database, which will make it messy to query and give maintenance.

## Conclusions

The first solution gives me a better table, at the cost of having to retrieve the labels via an additional service, every time I need them. 
The second solution keeps the code of the entities clean, but the SQL table messy, with many columns for all entities that will need translation.

How would you approach this? Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance for all the feedback!

Comment: desktop or web application?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the reason behind your questioning. It shouldn't really make a difference. In this case, there are many clients to this application (multiple apps, browser version, etc). This is about the data structure in the backend.

Comment: Deskop app should read string once and cache. These are few Polish transaltion solutions, and using JPA works bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue with the first approach described.
Additionally, I cached the queries with PreparedStatements and they perform really well. In addition to set single translations, I also created bulk editing and bulk retrieving methods, which performed even better.

Answer (score 4):

We solved this problem by seperating the translation for each entity and keeping normalisation, so therefore excluding the translation from the main entity, so for one example entitity of yours:

```
CREATE TABLE question(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  origin_date DATE; --Put all fields that don't change via language here
);

-- Create a translation table for the above entity and put all fields that 
-- change through internationalization here for example name and description

CREATE TABLE question_translation(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  question_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES question(id),
  language_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES language(id), --we have a separate table for languages so normalisation is provided
  name TEXT,
  description TEXT,
  UNIQUE(question_id , language_id) 
);
```

Example data for both tables would now be:

**Table language (for example):**

```
id    iso_a2_code
------------------
5     DE
12    EN
```

**Table question:**

```
 id    date
 ----------------
 1     19.04.2018
```

**Table question_translation:**

```
id     question_id    language_id    name    description
--------------------------------------------------------- 
1      1              5              TestDE  Description in DE
2      1              12             TestEN  Description in EN
```

JavaCode for Entities (not tested):

**Question:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @Column
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<QuestionTranslation> questionTranslations = new HashSet<>();

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
    private LocalDate date;

}
```

**Question Translation:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_translation")
public class QuestionTranslation  {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
    private LanguageEntity language;

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is more or less what I wrote in my solution 3. The main problem I see with this solution is, if you want to translate many fields in many entities, the number of tables in your database will grow a lot. Specially if you are using Envers,

Comment: Yes you are right it will grow, but i guess it is a very clean way of doing it. We had several hours of discussions about it and since you asked about the most elegant solution, i would prefer this one, we applied it and it worked out great (for a lot of tables).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution - https://github.com/azerphoenix/spring-i18n-demo

You can take a look to this demo project.